# Python, faking module in Class definition

Tags: python

I suspect this is one of those questions that will result in "Why do you want to do that?" but here goes:

I need to find a way to fake the module of a class defined in `__main__`; ie:

Lets say we have a.py:

```
class A(object):
    name = "a"
    pass
```

And b.py:

```
import inspect
import a

class B(object):
    __name__ = a.__name__
    name = "b"
    pass

print inspect.getmodule(B)
```

Calling b.py results in:

```
<module '__main__' from 'b.py'>
```

So, how do I get the module of class A taken to be b, without moving it into b ?

Comment: <insert obligatory question here>

Comment: As in why do I want to do this?

Comment: No, as in "Do you prefer red wine or white with aged cheddar?".

Comment: Red always. Who has White with cheese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the class's `__module__` attribute, but there are caveats:

```
class A(object):
    __module__ = 'b'
```

The main caveat is that this will cause `getmodule` to return None if the module `b` has not imported at the time you call `getmodule(A)`.  I think it's also possible for problems to arise if you import `b` in some nonstandard way, like importing it via an implicit relative import instead of as part of a package (if it's part of a package).

Conceptually, though, what you're doing is somewhat dubious.  It's risky to set A's module to be some other module, because that module might not be known (i.e., imported) when the real module is, and in fact it's possible the "disguise" module might not even exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realise that this is not that root cause of my problem.